# Corrupt sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/solr_admin/solr_resources in Datastax

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My DSE version is 4.7.3.
 I got error "Corrupt sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/solr_admin/solr_resources-a31c76040e40393b82d7ba3d910ad50a/solr_admin-solr_resources-ka-9808=[TOC.txt, Index.db, Digest.sha1, Filter.db, CompressionInfo.db, Statistics.db, Data.db]; skipping table"

so getting time out error while inserting records. After restart node the issue temp fixed but after some hours again i got time out error when insert records. 
Kindly help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can get this if the server is being killed and not allowed to shutdown cleanly.  Caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10501.  I would recommend updating to 4.8.11 or 5.0.4 (or later) to rule them out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below mentioned step :

1) Try to rebuild the sstable on the node using "nodetool scrub"
   http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsScrub.html
   If issue still don't get solved, follow below step

2) Shutdown the dse node.

3) Scrub the the sstable using  "sstablescrub [options]  "
   http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableScrub_t.html

4) Remove the corrupt SSTable

5) Stare dse service in dse node

6) Repair using "nodetool repair"